# NelmioApiDocBundle not generate documentation

Tags: php, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

I want to use NelmioApiDocBundle for generating documentation automatically. I fallowed standard Symfony doc to install and configure it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html. Unfortunately when I go to /api/doc my doc is empty.

I use Symfony 3.4 and NelmioApiDocBundle in v. 3.2.0.

Here is my config:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        path_patterns: # an array of regexps
            - ^/api(?!/doc$)
        host_patterns:
            - ^api\.
    documentation:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        schemes: [http, https]
        info:
            title: Thanatos API
            description: This is documentation of Thanatos
            version: 1.0.0
        security:
            - Bearer: []
```

And annotations in my controller (in beginning I want to see any data in my documentation):

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *  "/",
 *  name="thanatos_dashboard_index", 
 * )
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="Returns the rewards of an user",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *         type="array",
 *         @SWG\Items(ref=@Model(type=Reward::class, groups={"full"}))
 *     )
 * )
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="order",
 *     in="query",
 *     type="string",
 *     description="The field used to order rewards"
 * )
 * @SWG\Tag(name="rewards")
 * @NelmioSecurity(name="Bearer")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render("@AppThanatos/Dashboard/index.html.twig");
}
```

In /api/doc I see "No operations defined in spec!". What am I doing wrong?

---

@UPDATE

I just start to use Sami: http://symfony.com/projects/sami

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: I did not have time to resolve this problem. I just start to use Sami.

Comment: You haven't specified a method.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem. Working on my Mac I have always *ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE* (using Chrome) but in the production environment the same configuration works fine.

The only difference was Xdebug, I've tried disabling the module and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The assets normally are installed by composer if any command event (usually `post-install-cmd` or `post-update-cmd`) triggers the `ScriptHandler::installAssets` script. If you have not set up this script, you can manually execute this command:

```
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

Replace

```
 * @Route(
 *  "/",
 *  name="thanatos_dashboard_index", 
 * )
```

By

```
 @Rest\Get("/getVehicles")
```

And, in your action controller, return array or object like this :

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    return $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Vehicle')->findAll();
```

Comment: So, at this moment I create simple CRUD app. Is it possible to generate documentation for CRUD using NelmioApiDocBundle?

Comment: I think is no possible but I dont never try this